# Hyperbolic lens shape and aspheric surfaces

Tags: optics, differential-geometry, refraction, geometric-optics, lenses

In Optics, Hecht, the author states that the perfect surface for a lens shape will be a hyperbola.

[image]

He essentially derives this answer by writing the optical path length from F1 to A, then A to D, and putting the condition that the sum of this path length must be constant, from which we get this equation.
[image]

I can hand derive and confirm that this equation leads to a hyperbola. However, I believe the main property of a hyperbola is that the difference between the distance of a point from F1 and F2 is always constant, taking the value of 2a. I'm confused how the above equation and this standard definition of hyperbola correspond.

Answer (score 0):

The standard definition (difference of distance = const) and the shape of the ideal lens are just two properties of the same shape. They don't conflict with each other. From the standpoint of optics, the std. definition means that the interference pattern due two mutually-coherent point sources is a set of hyperbolae with the sources at their focus as in the figure below (In the figure, I ignored the 1/r amplitude decay of the spherical waves)[image: Interference pattern due to two point sources]